# AngularJS: How to listen to DOM Events?

Tags: angularjs

i am new to AngularJS so please forgive me this dump question. 
**How do I listen to 'dom' events like 'click'  or 'mousemove'?**

This is what I got (No errors, but also no result in the console)

// Code is based on the orginal angularjs-seed.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.$on('dragover', function() {
            console.log('dragover');
        });

        $scope.$on('click', function() {
            console.log('click');
        });

  }])

  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }]);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In AngularJS, events are usually handled by the [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks. During DOM compilation
>   directives are matched against the HTML and executed. This allows
>   directives to register behavior, or transform the DOM.

For the "click" event you would use [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()">Click me</button>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
  $scope.doSomething = function(){
    // do something...
  };
}
```

---

For the "dragover" event (and other events which are not already covered with Angular native directives) you would write your own directive:

HTML:

```
<div drop-target>Drop here</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('dropTarget', function(){
    return function($scope, $element){
      $element.bind('dragover', function(){
        // do something when dragover event is observed
      });
    };
  })
```

Comment: I think that `$element.on` is more appropriate with latest versions (`$element.bind` is still supported), as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913650/whats-the-difference-between-element-bind-and-element-on .

Answer (score 1):

ngClick and ngMouseover are supported out of the box, but you will need to write your own directive for drag events, or better yet, use a third party module that's already been written. I managed to get this drag and drop module working for my code:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-draganddrop