# What's the difference between element.bind and element.on

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I have been following examples of angularjs directives. I see some people use:

```
element.bind('click',callback)
```

while others use:

```
element.on('click',callback)
```

Any clue on what is the difference between the two and which should be applied when ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no functional difference. jQuery officially deprecated all binding syntaxes other than `.on`. Because jqlite `angular.element` is based on jQuery, they moved the syntax to `.on` inorder to be more compliant for those who use jQuery and Angular together. jqlite still allows for `.bind` to be backwards compatible (as does jQuery).

You can learn more about the differences here : [jquery .bind() vs. .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847021/jquery-bind-vs-on)

Comment: AngularJS does not support selectors for `.on()` which basically makes it useless compared to jQuery's alternative :(